# If $0<c<1$, then show $0<c^2<c<1$.

Tags: real-analysis

Exactly the title. I need to show that if $0<c<1$, then $0<c^2<c<1$.

Comment: Since $c>0$ and $c<1$, $c^2=c\cdot c<1\cdot c=c$.

Comment: Now, Exercise : If $c<1,$ what happens to the sequence $c, c^2, c^3 \cdots c^k \cdots$?

Comment: This reminds me of a story my cousin told me about his college fraternity: they had a list of all the people currently in the "square root club." To get into the club, the square root of your GPA had to be less than your GPA. :/

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**. We automatically have the right-most inequality $c<1$, so omit it and compare: $$0<c<1\quad\text{and}\quad0<c^2<c$$ What operation gets you from the first to the second?

Answer (score 7):

We have that $0<c<1$. Multiply the whole thing by $c$ and we get

$0\cdot<c\cdot c<1\cdot c\rightarrow 0<c^2<c$.

Then, by the original statement $0<c<1$, we have that $0<c^2<c<1$.

Thus, if $0<c<1$, then $0<c^2<c<1$.

Comment: You are missing a $c$ after the $0\cdot$ on your first math line.